# How to make white pixel values black by keeping rest of pixel value as it it from an image

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

i have an gray scale image which is showing black background, white leaf and some other color disease spots on it.
What i want to do make white portion into black and making other than black and white pixels color into white.

[image: Input Image]

[image: Desired Output]

```
img2 = cv2.imread('binary.jpeg')
binarr = np.where(img3 < 255 or img3 > 0, keep as it is, else make it 0)
plt.imshow(binarr)
```

but this seem like not supported by python.

any other suggestion to do this?

Comment: in a gray scale image there are 0-255 pixels, I want to make pixel =255 value as 0 and any value between pixel 1-254 make it as 255. I hope that clarify question.

Answer (score 0):

I labelled your question for numpy so you may get a better answer, also it is not clear what data type `cv2.imread()` actually returns so I've made an assumption it could be a list in which case:

```
binarr = [0 if pixel == 255 else 255 for pixel in img]
```

ie:

```
>>> img = [0,255,0,255,158]
>>> binarr = [0 if pixel == 255 else 255 for pixel in img]
>>> binarr
[255, 0, 255, 0, 255]
```

Comment: No its not like that.. If you see above given image closely it is made up of more than three colors (white, black and green, blue dots etc) what i want to convert white color into black as well and any other color into white one.

Comment: So not grayscale at all then?
"i have an gray scale image"